# How to use Server.MapPath to get location on network in classic asp

Tags: file-io, asp-classic, vbscript

I am listing filenames from folder on the network. I am using VBScript compliant code for Server.MapPath to locate folder on network:

```
<%Set FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set farFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("\server\folder"))%>
```

I am getting error of Path Not Found. The network is well up and working. I am not sure if this is the way we can address the network folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Set farFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("..") & "\server\folder" )

not sure if all versions of IIS allows   ("..")

Comment: thanks for the answer Alvaro, but I figured it out. For this case, we can just use FSO.GetFolder("server\folder"), it worked like a charm.